# Is my statement not updating because of the way I have it layed out?

Tags: php, mysql

This "page" is part of many that are all linked together using includes, but because I can't make it work I'm going straight to the url that relates to this exact page, and I still can't make it work, or figure out why.

What is supposed to happen, is the query checks if that `stock` is in the db, if it is, echo the values of the row, and if a submit button is pressed update the db based on the input values. If it's not in, echo the blank form, and if a submit button gets pressed insert into the db. I can't get either update or insert to work.

I'm going to post the entire page (minus the mysql connect,)  so hopefully someone can spot an error.

```
    <?php

$status = 'Active';
$stock = (isset($_GET['stock'])) ? $_GET['stock'] : '';
$cat = (isset($_GET['cat'])) ? $_GET['cat'] : '';
include ('../helper_content/title_data.php');

/* WHAT CATEGORY DO WE WANT? */
if($cat == "Sales") {

    $table = "Titles";
    if($stock) {$where = "stock = $stock";}
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        $status = $status;
        $title_status  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['title_status']);
        $title_number  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['title_number']);
        $title_location  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['title_location']);
        $title_owners  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['title_owners']);
        $stock = $_GET['stock'];
    }

}


/* Begin Main Query */
$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE $where";
$result5 = $conn->query($sql5);
if ($result5->num_rows > 0) {

// Stock exists, so submit will Update dB 
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

        if ($update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `Titles` SET status=?, title_status=?, title_number=?, title_location=?, title_owners=? WHERE stock=?")){
            $update->bind_param('ssssii', $status, $title_status, $title_number, $title_location, $title_owners, $stock);
            $update->execute();
        };
        if ($update->execute == TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating: " . $update->error;
        }
    }

// Display the HTML results
    while($row5 = $result5->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "Found In Database";

    // Title Number
        $title_number = 'value="'.$row5['title_number'].'"';
        $TitleStatus = $row5['title_status'];
        $TitleLocation = $row5['title_location'];
        $Owners = $row5['owners'];
    }
} else {
// No Query Results Found

    echo "Not Found In Database";

// Insert into dB
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

        if ($add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `Titles` status=?, title_status=?, title_number=?, title_location=?, title_owners=? WHERE stock=?")){
            $add->bind_param('ssssii', $status, $title_status, $title_number, $title_location, $title_owners, $stock);
            $add->execute();
        };

        if ($add->execute == TRUE) {
            echo "Record added into database";
        } else {
            echo "Error adding: " . $add->error;
        }
    }

/* End Main Query */
}


// Title Status
    foreach($title_statuses as $title_status){
        $selected = ($TitleStatus == $title_status) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
        $Title_status .= '<option value="'.$title_status.'"'.$selected.'>'.$title_status.'</option>';
    }

// Title Location
    foreach($title_locations as $title_location){
        $selected = ($TitleLocation == $title_location) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
        $Title_location .= '<option value="'.$title_location.'"'.$selected.'>'.$title_location.'</option>';
    }

// Prior Owners
    foreach($prior_owners as $owners){
        $selected = ($Owners == $owners) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
        $Owners_drop .= '<option value="'.$owners.'"'.$selected.'>'.$owners.'</option>';
    }

?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?stock=<?php echo $stock; ?>">
<section class="title">
<h3>Title Info - Stock #:<?php echo $stock; ?></h3>
    <p>
        <label for="title_number" class="inline-edit">Title Num</label> 
        <input type="text" name="title_number" id="title_number" size="20" spellcheck="false" <?php echo $title_number; ?>> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="title_status" class="inline-edit">Status</label> 
        <select name="title_status" id="title_status">
            <option></option>
            <?php echo $Title_status; ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="title_location" class="inline-edit">Location</label> 
        <select name="title_location" id="title_location">
            <option></option>
            <?php echo $Title_location; ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="title_owners" class="inline-edit">Owners</label> 
        <select name="title_owners" id="title_owners">
            <option></option>
            <?php echo $Owners_drop; ?>
        </select> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.vehiclehistory.com/paging-vin-report-data/specifications.php?vin=<?php echo $vin; ?>"><i class="fa fa-history" aria-hidden="true" title="Vehicle History"></i></a>
    </p>
</section>

<input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `$_GET['stock']` when your conditional says the correct verb is POST?

Comment: Because the "real" $stock is normally in one of the other include pages, I just put that $stock and $cat statement there to test.

Comment: I'm referring to the GET under `/* WHAT CATEGORY DO WE WANT? */`

Comment: check for mysql errors

Comment: Because the entire site is only 5 pages, but pulls data from over 30 tables in the database, based on the "cat" (meaning category to determine what data from what table to show; Sales, Sold, Payable, Receivable, etc.)

Comment: Error updating: Found In Database when submitting, but not even what the  error is.

Comment: oh i see now... `if($cat == "Sales") {` this is problem because `$cat` = ''

Comment: I think one of your major problems here is that your code isn't really organized all that well. For instance, the $sql5 query assumes this is a GET request, since $where is not set otherwise - `"Where stock = "` would not be a valid where clause..

Comment: @Tieson T - I will admit that, but that's only because I am trying to learn... Can you show me a better way? If I knew I wouldn't have titled the question the way I did...

Comment: hes right, main problem here is in get method and `stock` and `cat`, and how to behave when they aren't setted as expected add this `if($cat == "Sales") { ... } else { echo 'cat is not setted well'; die(); }` and you will see

Comment: when I add your code I get the same message when I hit submit and try to update a  stock that is in there: "Error updating: Found In Database", which is my echo statement, but I dont get a real error and nothing in the db updates.

Comment: ok then edit this `echo "Error updating: " . $update->error;` to `echo "Error updating: " . $conn->error;`

Comment: Now I have an error when I submit "Not Found In DatabaseError updating: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'status=?, title_status=?, title_number=?, title_location=?, title_owners=? WHERE' at line 1"

Comment: enable php error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: A MILLION errors...Not Found In Database
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/dbookatay/carcityofdanbury.com/Admin/include/pages/vehicle_Titles.php on line 78
Error updating: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'status=?, title_status=?, title_number=?, title_location=?, title_owners=? WHERE' at line 1

Can't even post them all because it's to many characters.

Comment: then go step by step over all errors and fix them, allways keep error reporting enabled during development phase, now you know that in file `veh‌​icle_Titles.php` on line 78 is variable which is not an object so find line where you setting up this variable, print it to see what happening and so on

Comment: Will do. Thanks! All my error messages are these foreach statements:  foreach($title_statuses as $title_status){
  $selected = ($TitleStatus == $title_status) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
  $Title_status .= '<option value="'.$title_status.'"'.$selected.'>'.$title_status.'</option>';
 }

those variable are arrays in the include('../helper_content/title_data.php');

Answer (score 1):

I would start by organizing your code a little differently. You have one of two things that can be true: either the form was submitted (a POST request), or the page was requested via URL (a GET request). So, start with this:

```
<?php

    # Data for dropdowns
    include ('../helper_content/title_data.php');

    $error = array();

    $status = "Active";
    $title_number = "";
    $title_status = "";
    $title_location = "";
    $title_owners = "";
    $vin = "";

    # Was the form submitted via POST?
    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
        # Yes

        # Is this a new stock item?
        if(empty($_POST['stock']))
        {
            # Yes - insert

            /*
                ... get your variables from the $_POST array
            */
            $title_number = filter_var($_POST['title_number'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            # ... repeat for other variables

            if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `Titles` (`status`,`title_status`,`title_number`,`title_location`,`title_owners`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssii', $status, $title_status, $title_number, $title_location, $title_owners);

                if ($stmt->execute()) 
                {
                    $stmt->close();

                    header('Location: ./?inserted=true');
                    exit();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $error[] = "Error adding: " . $stmt->error;
                    $stmt->close();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            # No - update
            $stock = $_POST['stock'];

            /*
                ... get your variables from the $_POST array
            */

            if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `Titles` SET status=?, title_status=?, title_number=?, title_location=?, title_owners=? WHERE stock=?"))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssii', $status, $title_status, $title_number, $title_location, $title_owners, $stock);

                if ($stmt->execute()) 
                {
                    $stmt->close();

                    header('Location: ./?updated=true');
                    exit();
                } 
                else {
                    $error[] = "Error updating: " . $stmt->error;
                    $stmt->close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        # No - assume a GET
        $status = 'Active';
        $stock = $_GET['stock'];
        $cat = $_GET['cat'];

        if(isset($_GET['updated']))
        {
            $message = "Record updated";
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['inserted']))
        {
            $message = "Record added into database";
        }

        if($stock != "")
        {
            # Load the item?
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `Sales` WHERE stock=?";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $stock);

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $result = $stmt->get_result();

                if($result)
                {
                    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

                    $title_number = $row['title_number'];
                    $title_status = $row['title_status'];
                    $title_location = $row['title_location'];
                }
            }

            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
?>

<?php if(isset($message)) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <?= $message ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(isset($error)) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
        <?php foreach($error as $err): ?>
            <li><?= $err ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <section class="title">
        <h3>Title Info - Stock #:<?= $stock; ?></h3>
        <input type="hidden" name="stock" value="<?= $stock; ?>" />
        <p>
            <label for="title_number" class="inline-edit">Title Num</label> 
            <input type="text" name="title_number" id="title_number" size="20" spellcheck="false" value="<?= $title_number; ?>" /> 
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="title_status" class="inline-edit">Status</label> 
            <select name="title_status" id="title_status">
                <option></option>

                <?php foreach($title_statuses as $option): ?>
                    <option <?= $option == $title_status) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?= $option ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="title_location" class="inline-edit">Location</label> 
            <select name="title_location" id="title_location">
                <option></option>

                <!-- Repeat the same process as $title_statuses -->
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="title_owners" class="inline-edit">Owners</label> 
            <select name="title_owners" id="title_owners">
                <option></option>

                <!-- Repeat the same process as $title_statuses -->
            </select> 
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.vehiclehistory.com/paging-vin-report-data/specifications.php?vin=$vin">
                <i class="fa fa-history" aria-hidden="true" title="Vehicle History"></i>
            </a>
        </p>
    </section>

    <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here's a partial re-implementation of your page. I'm starting with the assumption that a stock number was part of the requesting URL, and looking that value up. I (for the moment) am ignoring loading the dropdown values in favor of getting a basic lookup to work.

You'll also notice I've switched to using shorttags in your markup - this is generally a more concise method of templating than sprinkling echos all over the place.

I've added a partial implementation of some save logic. You'll also notice that I added a hidden input to your form - you don't want to rely on a query string value when posting a form.

The code stores some simple error messages in an array, which gets echoed out if the insert or update fails. If successful, we redirect back to the same page with a simple flag variable, which we read on *that* request to know if we need to display an informational message. This is known as POST-REDIRECT-GET, and prevents users from accidentally (or purposefully) resubmitting the same form data over and over.

Comment: I am working through organizing the rest the code into a better sample, but this should get you started.

Comment: I'm assuming the `include` is bringing in some markup - don't include that on a POST, since you want to be able to execute a redirect (will get to that eventually).

Comment: Your code, cut and pasted line by line got rid of all but 1 error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/dbookatay/carcityofdanbury.com/Admin/include/pages/vehicle_Titles.php on line 38"

Comment: Thank you, because I like learning the "correct" way to do things, and not just a "hacked" together page.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm writing this off the cuff, as I don't actively code in PHP anymore. Meaning, this is untested, but is similar to code I used to write. Caveat emptor...?

Comment: As far learning PHP correctly, I thought this was a good book: https://www.amazon.com/Objects-Patterns-Practice-MATT-ZANDSTRA/dp/1484219953 - the older versions might be cheaper, or your local library might have a copy.

Comment: @BradGuy Okay, I've added a partial implementation of the save logic. Again, I can't pretend it's bug free, but the idea should be sound. One thing to note is that you have a WHERE clause in your INSERT - you need to remove that.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this. I copied all of your current code, and added my $conn script back in and still get this error: "
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/dbookatay/carcityofdanbury.com/Admin/include/pages/vehicle_Titles.php on line 21." Line 21 is the "# Is this a new stock item? POST."

Comment: If I remove the "where" part, how do I only affect the 1 stock # and not all of the "stocks" in that table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136990/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-brad-guy).

Comment: This is frustrating.... With help from Tieson T. I have a cleaner, "correctly" laid out code, but neither of the POST statements aren't working, and looking at the code I don't understand why.

Comment: @BradGuy Edit your *question* with what you have so far, not this answer. The edit button is below the tags list.